# Linq Query to Sum into new list

Tags: c#, linq

I want to create a 2nd list from 1st list to show the sum with descending order.

```
1st list :
     ID               Value
    1                  20
    2                  40
    3                  10

2nd List:
 ID               Value
1                  70
2                  50
3                  10
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823467/using-linq-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers-in-c-sharp

Comment: So what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var list1 = new [] { new { id = 1, Value = 20 },  new { id = 2, Value = 40 }, new { id = 3, Value = 10 } }.ToList();


        var list2 = list1.
                        Select(x => new { x.id, 
                                          Value = list1.Where(y => y.id >= x.id).Sum(z => z.Value) }).
                        OrderByDescending(x=>x.Value).ToList();
```