# Linq query to select records based on most recent sum

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing a method that selects customer records based on a group by with the most recent purchase total equal (passed to the method).
I did some search and nothing showed up that helps me to achieve the desired output.

```
 customerList.GroupBy(x=> x.CustomerID },
                      (key, result) =>
                      {
                       var orderedList = result.OrderByDescending(c => c.Date).ToList();

                      return new Customer
                      {
                          CustomerID = orderedList.First().CustomerID,
                          PurchaseID = orderedList.First().PurchaseID,
                          Price = orderedList.First().Price,
                     };
                   });
```

| CUSTOMERID | PURCHACEID | PRICE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 235 | 01-03-2021 |
| 1 | 12 | 230 | 01-03-2021 |
| 1 | 14 | 235 | 05-04-2021 |
| 1 | 15 | 535 | 06-04-2021 |
| 1 | 16 | 230 | 07-04-2021 |

If I'm looking for most recent total purchase price of 1000, I should get

| CUSTOMERID | PURCHACEID | PRICE | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 14 | 235 | 05-04-2021 |
| 1 | 15 | 535 | 06-04-2021 |
| 1 | 16 | 230 | 07-04-2021 |

Comment: It would be better to write your effort first

Comment: what happens when no combination sums equal to 1000?

Comment: It would simply returns nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to produce a separate list with the [cumulative sums](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823467/using-linq-to-find-the-cumulative-sum-of-an-array-of-numbers-in-c-sharp). You can then use `TakeWhile` to take items until some condition is reached

```
var list = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var sum = 0;
var cummulativeSums = list.Select(v => sum += v).ToList();
var result= list.TakeWhile((_, index) => cummulativeSums[index] < 7).ToList();
// 1, 2, 3
```

Or you could do it all in one go by creating intermediate pair of values.

```
var list = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var sum = 0;
var result = list.Select(value => (sum += value, value))
    .TakeWhile(pair => pair.Item1 < 7)
    .Select(pair => pair.value)
    .ToList();
```