# How can I convert this SQL Query into LINQ (OVER (PARTITION BY Date))

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Here's the query I'm trying to convert into Linq:

```sql
SELECT R.Code, 
       R.FlightNumber, 
       S.[Date], 
       S.Station,
       R.Liters, 
       SUM(R.Liters) OVER (PARTITION BY Year([Date]), Month([Date]), Day([Date])) AS Total_Liters
FROM S INNER JOIN
               R ON S.ID = R.SID
WHERE (R.Code = 'AC')
AND FlightNumber = '124'
GROUP BY  Station, Code, FlightNumber, [Date], Liter
ORDER BY R.FlightNumber, [Date]
```

Thanks for any help.

UPDATE: Here is the Linq code I'm trying it on; I cannot make the OVER PARTITION by Date.

```
var test = 
(from record in ent.Records join ship in ent.Ship on record.ShipID equals ship.ID                       

orderby ship.Station
where ship.Date > model.StartView && ship.Date < model.EndView && ship.Station == model.Station && record.FlightNumber == model.FlightNumber

group record by new {ship.Station, record.Code, record.FlightNumber, ship.Date, record.AmountType1} into g

select new { g.Key.Station, g.Key.Code, g.Key.FlightNumber, g.Key.Date, AmmountType1Sum = g.Sum(record => record.AmountType1) });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Stackoverflow isn't a site where you just post something and tell people "Fix it" or "Convert this", so in the future when you ask a question, please think of that.

Comment: In my experience, I have found linqer to be a really useful tool for converting t-sql to linq.  http://www.sqltolinq.com/  -  Comes with a 10 day free trial.

Comment: @JeremyWiggins OVER PARTITION isn't recognized in linqer i'm affraid..

Comment: You can do it easily in two steps. Execute query without SUM and calculate SUM on client side. Client means .NET code.

Comment: @LukLed I tried for hours of doing this. I tried creating a rollup function and I cannot make it done. I want something to sum by date (e.g. Over Partition By Date).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute query first without aggregation:

```
var test = 
(from record in ent.Records join ship in ent.Ship on record.ShipID equals ship.ID                       

orderby ship.Station
where ship.Date > model.StartView && ship.Date < model.EndView && ship.Station == model.Station && record.FlightNumber == model.FlightNumber

select new {ship.Station, record.Code, record.FlightNumber, ship.Date, record.AmountType1};
```

Then calculate sum

```
var result = 
    from row in test
    select new {row.Station, row.Code, row.FlightNumber, row.Date, row.AmountType1, 
    AmountType1Sum = test.Where(r => r.Date == row.Date).Sum(r => r.AmountType1) };
```

This should produce the same effect as database query. Code above may contain errors, because I wrote it only here.

Answer (score 1):

I've answered a similar thread on: [LINQ to SQL and a running total on ordered results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834753/linq-to-sql-and-a-running-total-on-ordered-results)

On that thread it was like this:

```
var withRuningTotals = from i in itemList    
                   select i.Date, i.Amount,    
                          Runningtotal = itemList.Where( x=> x.Date == i.Date).
                                                  GroupBy(x=> x.Date).
                                                  Select(DateGroup=> DateGroup.Sum(x=> x.Amount)).Single();
```

In you situation, you might have to join the two tables together first while grouping, then run the same concept above on the joined table result.