# Data Table Sum Issue

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a situation.

I have datatable that contains the Credit and Debit columns like this

```
Month     Credit     Debit
Sep       1422825      0
Oct         0        1422825
Oct       1695017.5    0
Nov         0         1400000
Nov         0         295018
```

I want a balance that should be shown like this

```
Month     Credit     Debit       Balance
Sep       1422825      0
Oct         0        1422825      (1422825 of Credit-1422825 of Debit)=0
Oct       1695017.5    0
Nov         0         1400000     
Nov         0         295018       (1695017.5 of credit-1400000+295018)=0.5
```

it should be shown on crystal report how to do it.

Comment: please help me doing this.

Comment: do you need to show the balance at the end of the month only. As in case of Nov. Or you need to show the balance in every row.

Comment: This is a running value problem. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver). It would be helpful if you would state version of SQL server. For examlpe, this is for [2005](http://geekswithblogs.net/Rhames/archive/2008/10/28/calculating-running-totals-in-sql-server-2005---the-optimal.aspx).

Comment: My SQL version is 2008.

Comment: for shekhar,
yes i need balance of every month but infront of debit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution optimized for 2005, I'm sure it works well on 2008.
(use integer for month, it's easier...)

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (Month int, Credit money, Debit money, Balance money)

DECLARE @RunningTotal money

SET @RunningTotal = 0

INSERT INTO @Temp
SELECT Month, Credit, Debit, null
FROM Datatable
ORDER BY Month

UPDATE @Temp
SET @RunningTotal = Balance = @RunningTotal + Credit - Debit
FROM @Temp

SELECT * FROM @Temp
```

**EDIT (this continues from first step):**

If you need to display total only last record in group (month) then you can use ranking function, like...

```
;WITH Temp2 AS
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY Month
            ORDER BY Credit DESC, Debit DESC -- whatever order inside group you need
        ) AS N
     FROM @Temp
)
SELECT
    Month,
    Credit, 
    Debit, 
    Balance = CASE WHEN N = 1 THEN Balance ELSE NULL END
FROM Temp2
```

This is not tested, code written directly from my head :P

Comment: Dear Ozren, Thnx for your answer. it is really helpful, but dear i don't want to get the running total, instead i want running balance of every month. please review my question again. Really thnx God Bless You.

Comment: Your question looks like you need all rows, not one row per month. If you need one row per month then you use common sum + group by Month.

Comment: Dear Ozren,
can i do it using LINQ?

Comment: Mirza, that was not the question, and I would suggest to open another question for that if it weren't already asked. You can have running values evaluated using LINQ and there is a solution on SO here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834753/linq-to-sql-and-a-running-total-on-ordered-results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834753/linq-to-sql-and-a-running-total-on-ordered-results).